# Iterative algorithms with Spark streaming

Tags: scala, iteration, apache-spark, dstream

So I understand that Spark can perform iterative algorithms on single RDDs for example Logistic regression.

```
    val points = spark.textFile(...).map(parsePoint).cache()
    var w = Vector.random(D) // current separating plane
    for (i <- 1 to ITERATIONS) {
      val gradient = points.map(p =>
        (1 / (1 + exp(-p.y*(w dot p.x))) - 1) * p.y * p.x
      ).reduce(_ + _)
      w -= gradient
    }
```

The above example is iterative because it maintains a global state `w` that is updated after each iteration and its updated value is used in the next iteration.  Is this functionality possible in Spark streaming?  Consider the same example, except now `points` is a DStream.  In this case, you could create a new DStream that calculates the gradient with

```
val gradient = points.map(p =>
            (1 / (1 + exp(-p.y*(w dot p.x))) - 1) * p.y * p.x
          ).reduce(_ + _)
```

But how would you handle the global state `w`.  It seems like `w` would have to be a DStream too (using `updateStateByKey` maybe), but then its latest value would somehow need to be passed into the `points` map function which I don't think is possible.  I don't think DStreams can communicate in this way.  Am I correct, or is it possible to have iterative computations like this in Spark Streaming?

Answer (score 3):

I just found out that this is quite straightforward with the foreachRDD function.  MLlib actually provides models that you can train with DStreams and I found the answer in the [streamingLinearAlgorithm](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala) code.  It looks like you can just keep your global update variable locally in the driver and update it within the .foreachRDD so there is actually no need to transform it into a DStream itself.  So you can apply this to the example I provided with something like

```
points.foreachRDD{(rdd,time) =>

     val gradient=rdd.map(p=> (1 / (1 + exp(-p.y*(w dot p.x))) - 1) * p.y * p.x
     )).reduce(_ + _)

  w -= gradient

  }
```

Comment: It seems like you are using points, which from MLlib, do you know of any way to do such iterative programming using normal spark streaming? I have a similar requirement, where I would like to keep some gobal state by processing iteratively across microbatches in an ordered dstream.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... you can achieve something by parallelizing your iterator and then folding on it to update your gradient.

Also... I think you should keep Spark Streaming out of it as this problem does not look like having any feature which links it to any kind Streaming requirements.

```
// So, assuming... points is somehow a RDD[ Point ]
val points = sc.textFile(...).map(parsePoint).cache()
var w = Vector.random(D)

// since fold is ( T )( ( T, T) => T ) => T
val temps = sc.parallelize( 1 to ITERATIONS ).map( w )

// now fold over temps.
val gradient = temps.fold( w )( ( acc, v ) => {
  val gradient = points.map( p =>
    (1 / (1 + exp(-p.y*(acc dot p.x))) - 1) * p.y * p.x
  ).reduce(_ + _)
  acc - gradient
}
```

Comment: The question was specifically on the subject of spark streaming.

Comment: Good luck on your spark streaming adventure.